# Qt dialog not showing its widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I would like to create custom QT dialog (non-modal). Problem with my implementation is that it shows only dialog window with title, and no widgets that I've added to it.

Code below (I've ommited most of it, added just dialog and main window parts).

MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
/// some other stuff
private:
    std::unique_ptr<ui::DialogAddUpdateItem> addItemDialog;
/// some other stuff
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
/// some stuff
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
/// some stuff
    addItemButton = new QPushButton(tr("Add item"));
    QObject::connect(addItemButton, &QPushButton::pressed, this, &MainWindow::openAddItemDialog);
    navLay->addWidget(addItemButton);

    addItemDialog = make_unique<ui::DialogAddUpdateItem>(this);
/// some stuff
}


void MainWindow::openAddItemDialog() {
    addItemDialog->show();
    //addItemDialog->raise(); does not work with or without those functions
    //addItemDialog->activateWindow();
    //QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

DialogAddUpdateItem.h

```
namespace ui {
class DialogAddUpdateItem : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DialogAddUpdateItem(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QPushButton *buttonAcc, *buttonRevert, *buttonCancel;
    QGroupBox *centralWidget, *buttonsWidget;
    QLabel *labelName, *labelDescription;
    QLineEdit *textName;
    QPlainTextEdit *textDescription;
}
}
```

DialogAddUpdateItem.cpp

```
namespace ui {
DialogAddUpdateItem::DialogAddUpdateItem(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    if (!item) {
        setWindowTitle(tr("New object"));
    }

    centralWidget = new QGroupBox;

    QHBoxLayout *itemLay = new QHBoxLayout;
    centralWidget->setLayout(itemLay);

    labelName = new QLabel(tr("Name"));
    itemLay->addWidget(labelName);

    textName = new QLineEdit;
    if (item) {
        textName->setText(QString::fromStdString(item->getName()));
    }
    itemLay->addWidget(textName);

    labelDescription = new QLabel(tr("Description"));


    if (item) {
        textDescription = new QPlainTextEdit(QString::fromStdString(item->getDescription()));
    } else {
        textDescription = new QPlainTextEdit;
    }
    itemLay->addWidget(textDescription);

    buttonAcc = new QPushButton(tr("Save"));
    buttonAcc->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QObject::connect(buttonAcc, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogAddUpdateItem::acceptItem);

    buttonRevert = new QPushButton(tr("Revert"));
    buttonRevert->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QObject::connect(buttonRevert, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogAddUpdateItem::revertItem);

    buttonCancel = new QPushButton(tr("Cancel"));
    buttonCancel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    QObject::connect(buttonCancel, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogAddUpdateItem::cancelItem);

    buttonsWidget = new QGroupBox;
    itemLay->addWidget(buttonsWidget);
    QVBoxLayout *buttonsLay = new QVBoxLayout;
    buttonsLay->addWidget(buttonAcc);
    buttonsLay->addWidget(buttonRevert);
    buttonsLay->addWidget(buttonCancel);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DialogAddUpdateItem.cpp` the `centralWidget` has no parent, therefore it is not bound to anything and therefore not displayed. You should modify this:

```
centralWidget = new QGroupBox;
```

into this:

```
centralWidget = new QGroupBox(this);
```

Now the `DialogAddUpdateItem` will be the parent of the `centralWidget` and it should display it.

Also it seems like You are leaving some other widgets without a parent - it might cause trouble. For example the `QLineEdit textName` has this issue.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. As I understand, I should set parent of a widget to the widget it is displaying at. So label parent is centralWidget, centralWidget parent is DialogAddUpdateItem, etc?

Comment: Yes, You are pretty much right. I can't analyze Your code now, but I think You get the point. You just have to remember to maintain this parent-child relationship between various widgets.